# Zagier's "From 3-manifold invariants to number theory"?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, 3-manifolds

Zagier lectures on "From 3-manifold invariants to number theory" - do you know about texts of that or on the discussed web of ideas? ([https://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/de/node/10791])

Comment: Is anybody taking notes? I can’t attend, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following page there is some information on the lecture series. In particular, it is said that some student(?) has been taking notes which were initially private, but he decided to distribute it with kindness. You can find that through a link in that page.

https://www.math.sissa.it/course/phd-course/3-manifold-invariants-number-theory

Comment: Great, thank you!